# is it possible html text send to iMessage and also send to image with text to iMessage in our apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am beginner of iPhone. I have used iMessage in my apps, so is it possible image with text send to simultanesouly in iMessage. and html text is possible send in iMessage. give suggestion and source code..

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible, the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) only supports text. Not formatting or images are supported.

Also it will send the message via iMessage but will always fall back to SMS.